# Remove wifi network from Network-Manager "never" connected

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, network-manager

How can I clean Nm from all the network ID I never get connected too ?

Traveling and moving here and there increase the list of net and I don't need many of them ... so I would like to clean all the network that I never connect too.

I wonder if there is a built in command to clean the list.
I'm not good with bash but I think it is easy to create script and so a cron job.

A good starting point could be `nmcli` tool and in particular those command:

- `nmcli con delete`
- `nmcli con list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

```
nmcli --fields UUID,TIMESTAMP-REAL con list | grep never |  awk '{print $1}' | while read line; do nmcli con delete uuid  $line;    done
```

On newer Ubuntu  (15.10) use this command:

```
nmcli --fields UUID,TIMESTAMP-REAL con show | grep never |  awk '{print $1}' | while read line; do nmcli con delete uuid  $line;    done
```

It will be possibe also to use TIMESTAMP field to know how many day/month are passed from last connection, like for example we want to remove connection older than 1 year